# How do you position a larger NSImage inside of a smaller NSImageView programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Let's say I have an NSImage that's 100x100. I also have an NSImageView that's 50x50. Is there a way I can place the NSImage at coordinates inside the NSImageView, so I can control which part of it shows? It didn't seem like NSImage had an initWithFrame method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this in my NSImageView subclass, as Andrew suggested.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    NSRect cropRect = NSMakeRect(x, y, w, h);
    [image drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint
              fromRect:cropRect
             operation:NSCompositeCopy
              fraction:1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe so, but it's trivial to roll your own NSImageView equivalent that supports center/stretch options by drawing the image yourself.

Comment: Could I create an NSView, add a sub NSImageView at a position within?

Comment: Yeap, or better yet just create an NSView that draws an NSImage at your desired position.

Comment: I suppose better yet, crop the NSImage, since I'm slicing an image up into squares.

Answer (score 1):

Make your imageview as big as the image, and put it inside a scrollview.  Hide the scrollers if you want.  No need for subclassing in this case.

Answer (score 1):

NSImageView has a method `-setImageAlignment:` which lets you control how the image is aligned within the image view. Unfortunately, if you want to display part of the image that doesn't correspond to any of the `NSImageAlignment` values, you're going to have to draw the image programmatically.

Comment: Right. I want to slice up a big image into little boxes, so basic image alignment won't do it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your eventual goal is but the easiest thing to me seems to put your `NSImageView` inside an `NSView` (or a subclass – doesn't have to be `NSScrollView` as "@NSResponder" user suggests but this should work well too), set its `imageScaling` to `NSImageScaleProportionallyUpOrDown` and its `frameSize` to image's `size`. Then you can move your `NSImageView` freely around the upper view using `setFrame:myDesiredFrame`. No subclassing, no manual redrawing, etc.